# Enunciate - provide human readable name for REST resource

Tags: rest, enunciate

Enunciate generates REST resource names from `@Path` annotation. This is not really user friendly, especially for many resources with long URIs.

Is there a way to provide alternative name for REST resource?

Instead of:

```
/Account/userPK/{userPk}/birthday/{birthday}
```

something like:

```
Update Birthday - /Account/userPK/{userPk}/birthday/{birthday}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

It's a good idea for a new feature though. Wanna [open up an issue to track it](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE)?